# automated android builds on Windows platform

Tags: android, build-automation, android-build

I use hudson to make automated builds on unix. But is there any command line tools to setup automated build to generate apk file and sign it using my certificate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ant` to build your project, android SDK already includes configuration for it, can be found in `$ANDROID_SDK_DIR/tools/ant/build.xml`. See more information in [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Another way is to use [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/)

I use ant + msbuild + CruiseControl.Net

Comment: by the way, may be it is not the best idea to use that build.xml but instead generate one for your project http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html